# Как изменить ID на название?

Tags: sql, firebase

имеется такой код:

'''select product.name, postavka.name,prixod.date_prix, prixod.kol, product.ei

from prixod prixod

inner JOIN product product ON prixod.p_id = product.id

LEFT join postavka postavka ON prixod.post_id = postavka.id'''

и как заменить ID столбцов EI на их название (шт, л, кг)?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]